# GraphQL Asynchronous query results

Tags: graphql, batch-processing

I'm trying to implement a batch query interface with GraphQL. I can get a request to work synchronously without issue, but I'm not sure how to approach making the result asynchronous. Basically, I want to be able to kick off the query and return a pointer of sorts to where the results will eventually be when the query is done. I'd like to do this because the queries can sometimes take quite a while.

In REST, this is trivial. You return a 202 and return a Location header pointing to where the client can go to fetch the result. GraphQL as a specification does not seem to have this notion; it appears to always want requests to be handled synchronously.

Is there any convention for doing things like this in GraphQL? I very much like the query specification but I'd prefer to not leave the client HTTP connection open for up to a few minutes while a large query is executed on the backend. If anything happens to kill that connection the entire query would need to be retried, even if the results themselves are durable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not solved easily in a spec-compliant way. Apollo introduced the idea of a [@defer](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v2.4/features/defer-support/) directive that does pretty much what you're looking for but it's still an experimental feature. I believe Relay Modern [is trying to do something similar](https://medium.com/entria/relay-modern-network-deep-dive-ec187629dfd3).

The idea is effectively the same -- the client uses a directive to mark a field or fragment as deferrable. The server resolves the request but leaves the deferred field null. It then sends one or more patches to the client with the deferred data. The client is able to apply the initial request and the patches separately to its cache, triggering the appropriate UI changes each time as usual.

Comment: Thanks for the links, the information was really helpful. Part of the issue I was having was just not being able to google for anything because the terms "asynchronous" and "batch" are so heavily overloaded.

Comment: I think that's why "deferred" caught on. As an aside, it might be hackish, but you can probably use subscriptions for your use case as well.

Answer (score 1):

I was working on a similar issue recently. My use case was to submit a job to create a report and provide the result back to the user. Creating a report takes couple of minutes which makes it an asynchronous operation. I created a mutation which submitted the job to the backend processing system and returned a job ID. Then I periodically poll the `jobs` field using a query to find out about the state of the job and eventually the results. As the result is a file, I return a link to a different endpoint where it can be downloaded (similar approach Github uses).

Polling for actual results is working as expected but I guess this might be better solved by subscriptions.